# Resizing Numpy Matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix, resize

Say I have the following numpy matrix:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

And I want to resize this matrix to be a 4 x 4 and fill the missing values with 0's.

What I want is the following:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Where my original matrix is "maintained", so to speak. What numpy's resize function will actually do if I call it with .resize((4,4)) is the following:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

This appears to have taken items from some rows and added them to other rows in order to accommodate the new shape, then filled everything else in with zeroes, which isn't what I want.

How can I keep all my data in the "correct" rows place while adding these empty rows and columns?

Comment: make a `zeros` array of the right size, and copy your array to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`numpy.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) routine:

```
In [586]: m = np.ones((3,3))

In [587]: np.pad(m, ((0,1), (0,1)), mode='constant')
Out[587]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

---

Optional `constant_values` param used in `constant` mode indicates the values to set the padded values for each axis; defaults to `0`

Comment: How to fill it with a specific value besides 1 or 0 was going to be my follow up, good to know.

Answer (score 1):

The allocate and fill approach:

```
In [210]: arr = np.ones((3,3))
In [211]: res = np.zeros((4,4))
In [212]: res[:3,:3] = arr
In [213]: res
Out[213]: 
array([[1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

`np.pad` has more power when the fill is more complex, but for something this simple it is slower.  Look at its code if interested.  Regardless it's a good idea to know and understand this simple approach.

Comment: In this case, I need to fill it with a constant value so I can flag these new entries, so for my case Roman's answer is more fitting, but it's good to know the time complexities involved, I'll keep this in mind as well. Thanks!